# Proxy http nginx for multiple websites

Tags: nginx, proxy, http, redmine

I have to configure a Nginx server wich will be used as http(s) proxy and caching like a Apache server with proxy_pass and proxy_pass_reverse directives.

The system will be like this :
The nginx server respond to mydomain.com requests.
If I type mydomain.com/redmine, the nginx server have to proxy_pass on the internal adress (exemple : 192.168.0.207).
It's the same thing for other services (like mydomain.com/zabbix).
If I navigate on redmine, the URL will be mydomain.com/redmine/page1&param[...]
It's like using multiple proxy_pass and proxy_pass_reverse directives on a apache vhost.

I have troubles with sites like Redmine because if I click on a link on Redmine, mydomain.com/redmine/page1 redirect on mydomain.com/page1 and that makes a 404 error (the webpage is searched on the nginx server).
If I type directly mydomain.com/redmine/page1 it works.

How can I fix this problem ?
Thank you

**Edit**:

This configuration don't works for me.
For example, I tried :

```
location /pma {
    proxy_pass      http://192.168.1.208/phpmyadmin;
    proxy_redirect https://mydomain.com/ https://mydomain.com/pma/;
}
```

The login page is loaded correctly but when I try to log on, my browser open this link: `http://mydomain.com/phpmyadmin/index.php?lang=[...]` and gets a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

The [`proxy_redirect`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_redirect) directive can be used to modify redirects sent by backend servers. Based on your description of the behaviour, you need the following configuration:

```
proxy_pass http://192.168.0.207;
proxy_redirect http://mydomain.com/ http://mydomain.com/redmine/;
```

Try this for phpMyAdmin:

```
proxy_pass http://192.168.1.208/phpmyadmin/;
proxy_redirect http://mydomain.com/phpmyadmin/ http://mydomain.com/pma/;
```

Comment: Added suggestion for phpMyAdmin.

Comment: It don't works but when I try to log on, it sends me to http://mydomain.com/pma/index.php?lang[...] with the login page again and if I try to log on again, I get the 404 error with mydomain.com/phpmyadmin/index.php?lang[...]